# Refactored methods and binary compatibility in Java

Tags: java, refactoring, binary-compatibility

When refactoring methods it is easy to introduce binary incompabilities (with previous versions of the code) in Java.

Consider changing a method to widen the type of its parameter to a parent interface:

```
 void doSomething(String x);

 // change it to

 void doSomething(CharSequence c);
```

All the code that uses this method will continue to compile without changes, but it does require a re-compile (because the old binaries will fail with a MethodNotFoundError).

How about pulling a method up into a parent class. Will this require a re-compile?

```
// before
public class B extends A{
    protected void x(){};
}

// after
public class A {
    public void x(){};
}
public class B extends A{}
```

The method has been moved from B to the parent A. It has also changed visibility from protected to public (but that is not a problem).

Do I need to maintain a "binary compatibility wrapper" in B, or will it continue to work (automatically dispatch to the parent class)?

```
 // do I need this ?
 public class B extends A{
     // binary compatibility wrapper
     public void x(){ super.x(); }
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Widening" affects the signature of the method so that is not binary compatible.  Moving a method to a superclass does not affect the method signature, so it will work.  Eclipse has a great document that describes API and ABI compatibility:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs

More explicit rules are in part 2:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs_2

I believe you're interested in "Change type of a formal parameter" (i.e., what you refer to as widening) or "Move API method up type hierarchy" (i.e., what you refer to as pull into a parent class).

Answer (score -2):

It should continue to work automatically as Java has dynamic linking

Comment: I thought the same thing about the widened methods... That does not work because the class names of the arguments become part of the internal method name. I wonder if the same holds true with the name of the class that the compiler thinks declares the method.

Comment: "Widening" affects the signature of the method, but moving the method to a superclass does not.  Try it out on the commandline.

Comment: There are details of binary compatibility in the JLS.